# Does CiviMobileAPI generate any logs?

Tags: wordpress, api, mobile

I enabled CiviMobileAPI extension and Civi CRM Api Fix plug in (I'm using Wordpress) but can't login in the CiviMobile app (iOS). It keeps showing the Server API Error (Unknown error) message.

I wonder if there are any logs that can help investigate what can be causing this issue.

WordPress 5.2.2 with Primer theme
CiviCRM 5.15.1
Civi CRM Api Fix. plugin 1.0.0
CiviMobileAPI extension 4.0

CiviMobile iOS app 4.0

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure the directory for the extension is com.agiliway.civimobileapi and not com.agiliway.civimobileapi-master (or anything else after civimobileapi).? 
The directory has to be correct. 
Also do you have the new civicrm api fix? Or the old one?

Comment: Yes, the extension is under com.agiliway.civimobileapi directory. How do I check if I have the correct API fix? Though there was only one. The one I have installed is the plug in Version 1.0.0 | By Agiliway civicrm@agiliway.com

Comment: https://github.com/mecachisenros/civicrm-wp-rest

Comment: It worked! Although I couldn't find any reference to your rest plug-in anywhere in the civimobileapi documentation. Thanks a lot for your help. Hope that may help others facing the same issue.